# PHP reCAPHTCHA, Totally Lost

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm working to implement reCAPTCHA into a contact form & I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The reCAPTCHA field isn't showing on the page & it has removed my php footer include as well as the submit / reset buttons. Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing the verification correctly in my send-mail.php file.

**Contact Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="/bp/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>San Diego Ministries | 3223232323.com</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="Jesus Christ, Ministries, Salvation, Church San Diego, Small Group, Christian" />
<meta name="description" content="... is a San Diego based Ministry." />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean'
 };
 </script>



<!--/ CSS-->

<!--/ Events CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bp/css/prayer-request.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />



</head>

<body>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>



<!--/ Title-->

<div class="prayer-title"><img src="/bp/images/prayer-title.jpg"></img></div>



<!--/ Prayer Request Description-->


<div id="prayer-desc">

<p>
If you have a prayer request or question for one of our pastors, fill out the form below and one of our pastors will receive it and personally pray for you.
Thanks for sharing and giving us the opportunity to pray for you!
</p>

<p>
<b>Please note:</b> All contact fields are optional and your prayer requests are kept strictly confidential.
</p>

</div>



<!--/ Show Prayer Request Form-->

<div id="prayer-form">


<form name="prayer-form" action="send-mail.php" method="POST">

<label for="field_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name" placeholder="First Name, Last Name"> 
<br>
<label for="field_email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="field_email" name="sender_email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
<br>
<label for="field_phone">Phone:</label> <input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone" placeholder="(444) 444-4444">
<br>
<label for="field_message">Prayer Request:</label>

<textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message" placeholder="How can we pray for you?"></textarea>
<br>

    <?php
          require_once('/bp/recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "********************Po3UtfoqR1AzBk";
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>

<br>        
<input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>

</div>


<div class="bottom-block"><img src="/bp/images/white-block.jpg"></img></div>        


</body>
</html>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**Send-Mail.php**

```
  <?php
  require_once('/bp/recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "*******************yfYWTRW0hG7CrJ8hItb";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>



<?php     

$mail_to = "hel344323@gmail.com"; // specify your email here


// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables

$name = $_POST['sender_name'];

$mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];

$phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];

$web = $_POST['sender_web'];

$company = $_POST['sender_company'];

$addy = $_POST['sender_addy'];

$message = $_POST['sender_message'];


// Construct email subject

$subject = 'Email Web Prayer Request from ' . $name;


// Construct email body

$body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'Prayer Request: ' . $message;



// Construct email headers

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Your prayer request has been submitted - thank you.');

window.location = 'prayer-request.php';

</script>

<?php } else { ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Message not sent. Please, notify the site administrator admin@lsdlsdection.com');

window.location = 'prayer-request.php';
</script>

<?php

    }

?>
```

**[LINK TO WEBSITE](http://helmblanc.com/bp/prayer-request.php)**

Comment: Your mail form is vulnerable to mail header injection. Check the parameters to `mail`, so they can only contain valid values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a error in your PHP code. Could be a fatal error at this line,

`require_once('/bp/recaptchalib.php');`

I suspect file path for `recaptchalib.php` is wrong. I suggest turn ON PHP error and try again.

You can turn ON the error by adding this PHP code at the beginning of the file,

`ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);`

I hope this helps for now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log. By the sounds of it, your script is triggering a fatal error (most likely due to the path to the reCAPTCHA library being incorrect) which stops script execution, hence your site’s footer no longer displaying.